# Laravel dropzone problem for upload with product_id

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, dropzone.js

Suppose i have one product and it has many images . i used Dropzone js and if i upload images then its fine but if want to store with product_id then it pass null value . without passing any value its working fine. so how can i store both like image name and product_id at once ?
Here is my controller:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->hasFile('file')){

            $file= $request->file;
            $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $fileName =  time() .'-'.$fileName;
            $productImage = public_path("uploads/products/{$fileName}"); // get previous image from folder
            if (File::exists($productImage)) { // unlink or remove previous image from folder
                unlink($productImage);
            }
            $file->move('public/uploads/products/',$fileName);
            $image  = new Image();
            $image->image = $fileName;
            $image->product_id = $request->product_id;
            $image->save();

//            return redirect()->route('product.index');

        }
}
```

Database Schema :

```
 Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Error:

> message: "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot
>   add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`eshop`.`images`, CONSTRAINT `images_product_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`product_id`) REFERENCES `products` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON
>   UPDATE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `images` (`image`, `product_id`,
>   `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1538483231-blog-1-3.png, 123,
>   2018-10-02 12:27:11, 2018-10-02 12:27:11))"

Comment: are you sure that there is a product for 123 id in your products table ? it seems mysql doesn't find any record in products table which has 123 id

Comment: sorry i forgotten to remove static value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql gives " Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails " because you don't have any product in products table for 123 id. First you need to create that product. After that you can create relational records for it

Answer (score 0):

you cannot update table if some columns are foreign key in another table.

If you want to update if firstly drop the table which foreign key had`(images)`. After you can update this `products` table.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 3 reasons that might have a link to your problem:

1: it cold be that u need to make the column fillable in the model.

2: because u have it as a foreign_key u have to set the id automatically not with an insert  (gets from origin) or unbind the value.

3: it means that the value u are inserting does not exists on the origin table there for u are getting this error.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

> in @blade use

```
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" class="form-control m-input" value="{{$id}}">
```

instate of

```
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" class="form-control m-input" value="123">
```